# tkinter buttons not aligning

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm currently trying to create my window according to my wireframe. However, while using grid, my buttons get a weird space between them despite having the appropriate row distribution in the cells. I'm curious, what is going on here? How do I align these buttons properly?

Wireframe:[image]

Actual output:[image]
Notice the space between the "Clear" and "Compute" buttons.

Here is my code for the buttons:

```
clearButton = Button(window, text="Clear", width = 10)
clearButton.grid(row = 3, column = 3)
computeButton = Button(window, text="Compute", width=10)
computeButton.grid(row = 4, column = 3)
exitButton = Button(window, text="Exit", width = 10)
exitButton.grid(row = 5, column = 3)
```

Here is the code for the whole window:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

window = tkinter.Tk()

window.geometry('600x400')

yearLabel = Label(window, text="Year")
yearLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

amountLabel = Label(window, text="Amount")
amountLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)

rateLabel = Label(window, text="Rate")
rateLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)

monthlyPaymentLabel = Label(window, text="Monthly Payment")
monthlyPaymentLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 3)

totalInterestLabel = Label(window, text="Total Interest Paid")
totalInterestLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 3)




yearText = StringVar()
yt = Entry(window, textvariable=yearText)
yt.grid(row=0, column=1)

amountText = StringVar()
at = Entry(window, textvariable=yearText)
at.grid(row=1, column=1)

rateText = StringVar()
rt = Entry(window, textvariable=rateText)
rt.grid(row=2, column=1)




box = Listbox(window, height = 10, width = 50)
box.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan=3)

scroll = Scrollbar(window)

scroll.grid(row=2, column=2, rowspan = 6)

box.configure(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
scroll.configure(command = box.yview)


clearButton = Button(window, text="Clear", width = 10)
clearButton.grid(row = 3, column = 3)
computeButton = Button(window, text="Compute", width=10)
computeButton.grid(row = 4, column = 3)
exitButton = Button(window, text="Exit", width = 10)
exitButton.grid(row = 5, column = 3)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `grid` is like table in Excel - `clear` is in row with big `Entry` so its cell also use many spaces. You may have to use grid inside grid or inside pack. You can create grid with one row and two columns, in first column create inner grid (or pack) with all Entry and in second column create inner grid (or pack) with buttons.

Comment: You need to specify `rowspan` in `box.grid(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `rowspan = 3` to the `Listbox` `box`. So the `Listbox` `box` will take as much as the three buttons (Compute, Clear, Exit) take.
[image: Listbox takes equal space as three buttons]

Full Code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry('600x400')

yearLabel = Label(window, text="Year")
yearLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

amountLabel = Label(window, text="Amount")
amountLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)

rateLabel = Label(window, text="Rate")
rateLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)

monthlyPaymentLabel = Label(window, text="Monthly Payment")
monthlyPaymentLabel.grid(row=0, column=3)

totalInterestLabel = Label(window, text="Total Interest Paid")
totalInterestLabel.grid(row=1, column=3)

yearText = StringVar()
yt = Entry(window, textvariable=yearText)
yt.grid(row=0, column=1)

amountText = StringVar()
at = Entry(window, textvariable=yearText)
at.grid(row=1, column=1)

rateText = StringVar()
rt = Entry(window, textvariable=rateText)
rt.grid(row=2, column=1)

box = Listbox(window, height=10, width=50)
box.grid(row=3, column=0, rowspan=3, columnspan=3)

scroll = Scrollbar(window)
scroll.grid(row=2, column=2, rowspan=6)

box.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
scroll.configure(command=box.yview)


clearButton = Button(window, text="Clear", width=10)
clearButton.grid(row=3, column=3)

computeButton = Button(window, text="Compute", width=10)
computeButton.grid(row=4, column=3)

exitButton = Button(window, text="Exit", width=10)
exitButton.grid(row=5, column=3)

window.mainloop()
```

But if you want to make the buttons closer and the `Listbox` `box` take more space than the buttons then add `rowspan = 12`

[image: Buttons are close to each other and listbox takes more space]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to divide your master frame in multiple frames.
If the gui widgets get more complex then it will be a pain to do propper geometry.

I divided the master frame in 2 parts a top and a bottom so you don't need to deal with columnspan and rowspan which is  difficult by complex gui's.

I added pady and padx for the gap between widgets you may change it for the needed size.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry('600x400')

top_frame = Frame(window)
top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

yearLabel = Label(top_frame, text="Year")
yearLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30)

amountLabel = Label(top_frame, text="Amount")
amountLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)

rateLabel = Label(top_frame, text="Rate")
rateLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)

yearText = StringVar()
yt = Entry(top_frame, textvariable=yearText)
yt.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=30)

amountText = StringVar()
at = Entry(top_frame, textvariable=yearText)
at.grid(row=1, column=1)

rateText = StringVar()
rt = Entry(top_frame, textvariable=rateText)
rt.grid(row=2, column=1)

monthlyPaymentLabel = Label(top_frame, text="Monthly Payment")
monthlyPaymentLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 3, padx=30)

totalInterestLabel = Label(top_frame, text="Total Interest Paid")
totalInterestLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 3)


bottom_frame = Frame(window)
bottom_frame.grid(row=1, column=0 )

box = Listbox(bottom_frame, height = 10, width = 80)
box.grid(row=0, column=0)

scroll = Scrollbar(bottom_frame)

scroll.grid(row=0, column=1)

box.configure(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
scroll.configure(command = box.yview)

b_right_frame = Frame(bottom_frame)
b_right_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N)

clearButton = Button(b_right_frame, text="Compute", width = 10)
clearButton.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky=N)
computeButton = Button(b_right_frame, text="Clear", width=10)
computeButton.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky=N, pady=10)
exitButton = Button(b_right_frame, text="Exit", width = 10)
exitButton.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky=N)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: If the gui becomes even more complex then you should divide it further.

Answer (score 2):

below an oo solution.

Notice that the listbox is insert in a Frame separate from others.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,):

        super().__init__()

        self.master.title("Hello World")

        self.year = tk.IntVar()
        self.amount = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.rate = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.interest = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.payment = tk.DoubleVar()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        w = tk.Frame()

        r =0
        ttk.Label(w, text="Year:").grid(row=r, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Entry(w,width=8, textvariable=self.year).grid(row=r, column=1, padx=5, pady=5,sticky=tk.W)

        r =1
        ttk.Label(w, text="Amount:").grid(row=r, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Entry(w,width=8, textvariable=self.amount).grid(row=r, column=1, padx=5, pady=5,sticky=tk.W)

        r =2
        ttk.Label(w, text="Rate:").grid(row=r, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Entry(w,width=8, textvariable=self.rate).grid(row=r, column=1, padx=5, pady=5,sticky=tk.W)

        r =0
        ttk.Label(w, text="Monthly Payment:").grid(row=r, column=3, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Entry(w,width=8, textvariable=self.payment).grid(row=r, column=4, padx=5, pady=5,sticky=tk.W)

        r =1
        ttk.Label(w, text="Total Interest Paid:").grid(row=r, column=3, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Entry(w,width=8, textvariable=self.interest).grid(row=r, column=4, padx=5, pady=5,sticky=tk.W)

        c =5
        bts = [('Clear', self.on_clear),
               ('Compute', self.on_compute),
               ('Exit', self.on_exit),]

        for r, btn in enumerate(bts):
            b = ttk.Button(w, text=btn[0], underline=0)
            b.bind("<Button-1>", btn[1])
            b.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=tk.W+tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)

        w.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.W+tk.S+tk.E)

        w2 = tk.Frame()

        self.get_listbox(w2,0,0,10,45).grid(padx=5, pady=5)

        w2.grid(sticky=tk.W)

    def on_clear(self,evt=None):
        msg = "To assign!"
        messagebox.showwarning(self.master.title(),msg)      

    def on_compute(self,evt=None):
        msg = "To assign!"
        messagebox.showwarning(self.master.title(),msg)      

    def on_exit(self,evt=None):
        self.master.destroy()

    def get_listbox(self, container, row, col, height=None, width=None):

        sb = tk.Scrollbar(container,orient=tk.VERTICAL)

        w = tk.Listbox(container,
                    relief=tk.GROOVE,
                    selectmode=tk.BROWSE,
                    height=height,
                    width=width,
                    background = 'white',
                    font='TkFixedFont',
                    yscrollcommand=sb.set,)

        sb.config(command=w.yview)

        sb.grid(column=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.S)
        w.grid(row=row, column=col)

        return w        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A second version nearly equal your pic...I've moved buttons

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,):

        super().__init__()

        self.master.title("Hello World")
        self.year = tk.IntVar()
        self.amount = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.rate = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.interest = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.payment = tk.DoubleVar()

        self.init_ui()


    def init_ui(self):

        w = tk.Frame()

        r =0
        ttk.Label(w, text="Year:").grid(row=r, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Entry(w,width=8, textvariable=self.year).grid(row=r, column=1, padx=5, pady=5,sticky=tk.W)

        r =1
        ttk.Label(w, text="Amount:").grid(row=r, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Entry(w,width=8, textvariable=self.amount).grid(row=r, column=1, padx=5, pady=5,sticky=tk.W)

        r =2
        ttk.Label(w, text="Rate:").grid(row=r, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Entry(w,width=8, textvariable=self.rate).grid(row=r, column=1, padx=5, pady=5,sticky=tk.W)

        r =0
        ttk.Label(w, text="Monthly Payment:").grid(row=r, column=3, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Entry(w,width=8, textvariable=self.payment).grid(row=r, column=4, padx=5, pady=5,sticky=tk.W)

        r =1
        ttk.Label(w, text="Total Interest Paid:").grid(row=r, column=3, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Entry(w,width=8, textvariable=self.interest).grid(row=r, column=4, padx=5, pady=5,sticky=tk.W)

        w.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.W+tk.S+tk.E)

        #lisbox
        w2 = tk.Frame()

        self.get_listbox(w2,0,0,10,45).grid(padx=5, pady=5)

        w2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.W+tk.S+tk.E)

        #buttons
        bts = [('Clear', self.on_clear),
               ('Compute', self.on_compute),
               ('Exit', self.on_exit),]

        w3 = tk.Frame()

        for r, btn in enumerate(bts):
            b = ttk.Button(w3, text=btn[0], underline=0)
            b.bind("<Button-1>", btn[1])
            b.grid(row=r, column=0, sticky=tk.N, padx=5, pady=5)

        w3.grid(row=3,column =4, sticky=tk.N)


    def on_clear(self,evt=None):
        msg = "To assign!"
        messagebox.showwarning(self.master.title(),msg)      

    def on_compute(self,evt=None):
        msg = "To assign!"
        messagebox.showwarning(self.master.title(),msg)      

    def on_exit(self,evt=None):
        self.master.destroy()

    def get_listbox(self, container, row, col, height=None, width=None):

        sb = tk.Scrollbar(container,orient=tk.VERTICAL)

        w = tk.Listbox(container,
                    relief=tk.GROOVE,
                    selectmode=tk.BROWSE,
                    height=height,
                    width=width,
                    background = 'white',
                    font='TkFixedFont',
                    yscrollcommand=sb.set,)

        sb.config(command=w.yview)

        sb.grid(column=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.S)
        w.grid(row=row, column=col)

        return w        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]